# what does it mean "class LEVELDB_EXPORT Status" in leveldb?

Tags: c++, leveldb

I found that "LEVELDB_EXPORT" is predefined in "export.h" .

```
class LEVELDB_EXPORT DB{
}
#define LEVELDB_EXPORT
```

but i don't know which usage it is.

Comment: Probabaly theres an alternative definition using `__declspec(import)` or `__declspec(export)` for some configuration on windows to export the class from a dll, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

It explained in git commit [4a7e7f5](https://github.com/google/leveldb/commit/4a7e7f50dcf661cfffe71737650b0fb18e195d18) :

Add LEVELDB_EXPORT macro to export public symbols.

gcc defaults to exporting all symbols, but other linkers do not. Adding
the LEVELDB_EXPORT macro allows a project to set LEVELDB_SHARED_LIBRARY
when building/linking with leveldb as a shared library.

This is to allow leveldb to be created as a shared library on all
platforms support by Chrome and enables a fix for
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=764810.

This also has the benefit of reducing the shared library size from
418863 to 380367 bytes (64-bit Linux).

---

LEVELDB_EXPORT macro to export public symbols, That`s the answer I think.

Comment: thanks for that.I think it's the answer.